# Program using loops and random generator (beginning java)

Tags: java, loops, random

A drunkard in a grid of streets randomly picks one of four directions and stumbles to the next intersection, then again randomly picks one of four directions, and so on. You might think that on average the drunkard doesn't move very far because the choices cancel each other out, but that is not the case. Represent locations as integer pairs (x,y). Implement the drunkard's walk over 100 intersections, starting at (0,0) and print the ending location

Can anyone help? I'm completely lost with using random generators and loops in the same program

Below is what I have. It complies fine but doesn't print anything and I'm not sure if I got the random 100 intersection thing right

```
import java.util.*;

class Drunkard {
    int x, y; 
    Drunkard(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x; 
    this.y = y;
    } 
    void moveNorth() {
    this.y -= 1; 
    }
    void moveEast() {
    this.x += 1; 
    }
    void report() {
    System.out.println("Hiccup: " + x + ", " + y); 
    } 
} 

class Four {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random generator = new Random(); 
    Drunkard drunkard = new Drunkard(100, 100); 
    int direction; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        direction = Math.abs(generator.nextInt()) % 4; 
        if        (direction == 0) { // N
        drunkard.moveNorth();
        } else if (direction == 1) { // E
        drunkard.moveEast(); 
        } else if (direction == 2) { // S
        System.out.println("Should move South."); 
        } else if (direction == 3) { // W
        System.out.println("Should move West."); 
        } else {
        System.out.println("Impossible!"); 
        } 
        System.out.drunkard.report(); 
    } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far, what have you tried?

Comment: Help with what?  You haven't asked any real question other than "Can anyone help?"  The answer to that question is, "Probably."  And if you have code, you should post it.  If you don't have code, make an attempt at solving this yourself and then ask for help with a specific issue.

Comment: Use class [`java.util.Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) to generate random numbers.

Comment: So you want us to give you the solution to your homework?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to put in my code! Just added what I have

Comment: FYI: The instructions say to start him at 0,0; you're starting him at 100,100.

Comment: It definitely looks like it would print things.  Obviously you still need to implement moves for South and West, but I don't think that's the problem here.  How are you running your program, and where are you looking for the printed output?


EDIT: Are you sure this compiles?  On your last non-curly-brace line, you don't need the System.out part -- just call drunkard.report().

Answer (score 1):

your program will be:

> initialization
>
> loop: for 1 to 100, do:
>
> ```
> i = random()
>
> if i<=0.25 : go north
>
> if i>0.25 and i<=0.5 : go south 
>
> if i>0.5 and i<= 0.75 : go east
>
> if i>0.75 and i<= 1 : go west
> ```
>
> end loop
>
> show final point.

Answer (score 1):

I see a variety of problems:

- You are initializing your Drunkard's position to 100,100.  The assignment said to initialize to 0,0.
- `System.out.drunkard.report()` absolutely does not compile.  Just call `drunkard.report()`.
- The instructions say to print the final location, so you need to move the call to drunkard.report() down one line, so that it is outside of the for loop.
- You haven't written methods for moveSouth or moveWest.  Write them and add calls to them in the appropriate place.
- The class Four needs to be public in order to run it directly.
- Good Java programming practices say that every class should be in its own file, but this probably goes against what your instructor asked you to do.

But, I don't think that's your problem.  I think there's a problem with how/where you're trying to run the program.  You say it compiles fine but doesn't print any output.  You know that after it compiles there is another step to run the program, right?

To be clear, here's what you should be doing.  At a command line, make sure you are in the directory where your `.java` file lives.  I'm going to assume it's called `Four.java`.  Type the following, hitting enter after each line.  (Don't type the `$` prompt)

```
$ javac *.java
$ java Four
```

I copied the code you posted above, fixed the problems I highlighted, and followed my own instructions above; it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
int direction = (new Random()).nextInt(4);
```

And use this direction variable to determine where he walks to. I would use recursion in this case instead of a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This starts at 0,0. Generates a random number to determine location and updates the location.

- Not sure about the way you are generating the random number, this seems to work well for me.

  ```
  Point currentLocation = new Point();
  currentLocation.setLocation(0, 0);

  Point newLocation = new Point(0,0);

  Random random = new Random();

  //make 100 moves
  for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
  {
      int k = random.nextInt(4);
      if(k == 0)
      {
          //use your drunkard method here
          newLocation.setLocation(currentLocation.getX(), currentLocation.getY() + 5); 
      }
      else if (k == 1)
      {
          //go south
          newLocation.setLocation(currentLocation.getX(), currentLocation.getY() - 5);
      }
      else if (k == 2)
      {
          //go east
          newLocation.setLocation(currentLocation.getX() + 5, currentLocation.getY());
      }
      else if(k == 3)
      {
          //go west
          newLocation.setLocation(currentLocation.getX() - 5, currentLocation.getY()); 
      }
      currentLocation.setLocation(newLocation);
  }

  System.out.println(currentLocation);
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

You're not implementing your random generator to its full extent.

```
Random generator = new Random();
int    direction = generator.nextInt(4); // This will return a random int 
                                         // between 0 and 3
```

Some other useful tricks when using `Random()` are as follows:

```
int i = generator.nextInt(4)+2; // This will return a random int 
                                // between 2 and 5
```

I highly recommend you check out [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) if you'd really like to learn all of the neat tricks that you can do using the Random Class.

Answer (score 0):

All i did for this is create a loop that generated a random number between -1 and 1, and summed the values 100 times. Do that for x and for y.

```
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    //intial = (0,0)
    //North = (0, 1)
    //South = (0, -1)
    //East = (1, 0)
    //West = (-1, 0)

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        x += (int) (Math.random() * 3) + (-1);
        y += (int) (Math.random() * 3) + (-1);
    }
    System.out.printf("The Drunkard is now located at: (%d, %d)", x, y);
```